# "setFrame" doesn't work for UIScrollView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, frame

I've put a ScrollView in storyboard.

Next, in the code I call

```
self.scroll.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 800, 900);
```

I suppose the scroll should change the position into (100, 0)

But somehow it still remains in the original position where was set in storyboard.

What am I missing ?

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it won't work for any view in autolayout system at all if added using storyboard or xib.

If you want to set frame initialise in your code.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;

_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
```

If you want to set position in autolayout system you should consider updating the constraints of the view.

```
self.scrollViewWidthConstraint.constant += 20;
[self.scrollView updateConstraints];
```