# NSScrollView scrolling on AutoLayout

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, nsscrollview

I have a `NSScrollView` that is restrained to AutoLayout (fixed on `0x0` coordinates of the main view, `240px` fixed width and equaling the `height` of the main view).

The problem I have is that, when my content grows vertically it seems clipping doesn't understand what I want (vertical scroll enabling).

I tried both:

```
[self.leftMenu setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, menuWidth, 2000.0)];
[self.leftMenu setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(menuWidth, 2000.0)];
```

and trigger this too:

```
[self.leftMenu needsUpdateConstraints];
```

Yet with no change. I even tried to show the vertical scrollbar by default to see if that was the issue, but it really doesn't enable scrolling.

So my default view's `height` is `445px` (means the scrollview is overflowing with easily `1000px`) and when I resize the window it legally shows the overflowing content I had drawn programmatically.

I came by this [iOS-variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198375/setframe-doesnt-work-for-uiscrollview-in-ios) and this [older article](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/326783-guidelines-for-using-autolayout-with-nsscrollview.html) but don't really know what the correct approach is. Never had issues with this on iOS development, but these seemingly simple things are causing some minor annoyances.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are running into is because the spacing constraint needs to be negative where the content view is bigger than the scroll view. The diagram below explains what constraints should be placed on the content view.

[image: NSScrollView Layout Constraints]

The Leading, Trailing, and Top constraints of your content view should be 0 and the bottom should be -1555 (if the content view's height is 2000). Doing this will tell the scroll view how much scrolling it needs to do in order to show the entire view.

I hope this helps, I generally work with iOS so I have run into similar problems with UIScrollView. I know the two are not exactly the same but I tried to set up a simple project and test it with these constraints and I did get scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

NSScrollView doesn't allow you to modify the contentView and documentViews directly.  Your content is contained in some kind of view - for the default NSScrollView, there is an `NSView` inside an `NSClipView` inside the `NSScrollView`.

Whatever view you are using to hold the growing content, just re-assign that view to your `NSScrollView`'s documentView (after you have updated it's frame/size appropriatley).  That triggers the scrollview to recalculate everything and activate scrolling as needed.

```
view.addSubview(newButton)       //the view that contains your content
scrollView.documentView = view   //triggers everything to be recalculated
```

Hope this helps!